# How to save user generated editText field's to Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase and Android. I wanted to create an app in which a user can input a number of Foods he/she wanted to have and save it to Firebase. Now my problem is that instead of having the data saved one by one with its own unique key, the same instance of data is being saved. It's not iterating through the rest of the inputs.

[image: here is my Firebase data]

Here is my code for the user generated editText field's and saving them to Firebase.

```
public class AddMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText menu_added;
private LinearLayout lnrDynamicEditTextHolder;
private EditText edtNoCreate;
private Button btnCreate, btnSave;
private FirebaseAuth auth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_menu);

    lnrDynamicEditTextHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrDynamicEditTextHolder);
    edtNoCreate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNoCreate);
    btnCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(edtNoCreate.getText().toString().length()>0) {
                try {
                    lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.removeAllViews();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                final int length = Integer.parseInt(edtNoCreate.getText().toString());

                for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
                    final EditText editText = new EditText(AddMenuActivity.this);
                    editText.setId(i+1);
                    editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    editText.setHint("EditText "+(i+1));
                    lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.addView(editText);


                    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            for (int a=0;a<length;a++){
                            final String menu_add = editText.getText().toString().trim();


                            Query menuQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Establishment").orderByChild("Estabname").equalTo(menu_add);
                            menuQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                                        Toast.makeText(AddMenuActivity.this,"This Name has been taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(menu_add)) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter an Item!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        String menu_id = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                        DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Menu");
                                        DatabaseReference pushedPostRef = current_user_db.push();
                                        String postId = pushedPostRef.getKey();

                                        DatabaseReference current_user_db2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Menu").child(postId);

                                        Map newPost = new HashMap();
                                        newPost.put("Mfood_Name", menu_add);

                                        current_user_db2.setValue(newPost);

                                        startActivity(new Intent(AddMenuActivity.this, ManageEstablishmentActivity.class));

                                    }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });

                        }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the XML File

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtNoCreate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Number Of Food's"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCreate"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:text="Create" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:text="Save" />
</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrDynamicEditTextHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do  you want save number of food items along with food names??

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1):

Do like this -

```
Map newPost = new HashMap();
newPost.put("Mfood_Name", menu_add);
newPost.put("mfood_Quantity", itemQuantity);

current_user_db2.setValue(newPost);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase Realtime Database / Firestore, you can store array and list in the form of Hashmap ([Realtime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) / [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays)).

Example code snippet for Cloud Firestore:

```
public class MapPost {
    String title;
    Map<String,Boolean> categories;

    public MapPost(String title, Map<String,Boolean> categories) {
        this.title = title;
        this.categories = categories;
    }
}

Map<String, Boolean> categories = new HashMap<>();
categories.put("technology", true);
categories.put("opinion", true);
categories.put("cats", true);
MapPost myMapPost = new MapPost("My great post", categories);
```